# undefined: function (declared in another package)

Tags: go

my project organisation looks like this :

- GOPATH

  - src

    - cvs/user/project

      - main.go
      - utils

        - utils.go

main.go looks like this :

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "cvs/user/project/utils"
)

func main() {
   ...
   utilsDoSomething()
   ...
}
```

and utils.go :

```
package utils

import (
  "fmt"
)   

func utilsDoSomething() {
    ...
}
```

The compiler tells me that :

```
main.go imported and not used: "cvs/user/project/utils"

main.go undefined: utilsDoSomething
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any idea would be helpful, thank you in advance !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot the package prefix in `main.go` and your function is not [exported](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers), meaning it is not accessible from other packages. To export an identifier, use a capital letter at the beginning of the name:

```
utils.UtilsDoSomething()
```

Once you have the `utils` prefix you can also drop the `Utils` in the name:

```
utils.DoSomething()
```

If you want to import everything from the `utils` package into the namespace of your main application do:

```
import . "cvs/user/project/utils"
```

After that you can use `DoSomething` directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

In Go the symbols (including function names) starting with lower case letters are not exported and so are not visible to other packages.

Rename the function to `UtilsDoSomething`.

If you strongly oppose exporting this function and you are using Go 1.5 or later, you can make your function visible to only your project by placing `utils` directory inside `internal` directory.

[Specification of internal packages](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/edit)

Answer (score 1):

When you are referencing a function from a package you need to reference it using the `package name.Function name` (with capital case).

In your case use it as:

`utils.UtilsDoSomething()`.

Answer (score 0):

function name also needs to be capitalized in the package utils

```
func UtilsDoSomething()
```